# Controlling imagemagick output filenames with "printf"-style formatting directives

Tags: imagemagick

According to stuff I've read, I should be able to do:

```
convert -density 200 foo.pdf -quality 90 'output-%3d.jpg'
```

to get a set of JPG files with names like "output-001.jpg", "output-002.jpg", etc. However, what I get is "output-%3d-1.jpg", "output-%3d-2.jpg", etc. Including the "-" or not including it seems to make no difference.

I've tried

```
convert -density 200 foo.pdf -quality 90 -define filename:literal=false 'output-%3d.jpg'
```

with the same result. Using just "%d" instead of "%3d" works, but I don't want that; I want the leading zeros to make sorting easier. Am I just missing something obvious? I've seen multiple references to that filename pattern syntax but it just doesn't work for me.

I'm on up-to-date MacOS with fully updated Imagemagick if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

The "%3d" should be "%03d" to annotate the leading zeros.

```
convert -density 200 foo.pdf -quality 90 "output-%03d.jpg"
```

I tested on windows but I would imagine the same works on MacOS.